# Guardando array em banco de dados sem serializar

Tags: php, mysql

Estou construindo um website de rede social onde o usuário pode pertencer a grupos e fazer comentários a postagens.

Estou tentando guardar os membros de grupos e comentários de maneira limpa no banco de dados, de preferência sem serializar os arrays, mas não estou encontrando uma forma de fazê-lo.

Tinha pensado em guardar uma tabela com esses dados dentro das linhas de grupos e postagens, mas descobri que isto não é possível.

Existe alguma maneira limpa de guardar esses dados ou tenho mesmo que serializar os vetores de usuários e comentários?

Comment: Não é possível. Qual problema em serializar?

Comment: Você acha que dá mais trabalho usar serialize do que criar uma POG? Se você transformar um array em uma string usando os tipos de informação que você quer, será IMPOSSÍVEL reverter o processo assumindo que os comentários irão assegurar o uso de qualquer char por parte do usuário.

Answer (score 1):

### Solução 1

Gcanhete, o ideal é rever sua modelagem de banco de dados, deve haver uma forma limpa de armazenar os dados no banco, de preferência obedecendo as 3 primeiras normas formais.

Entendo que da forma que você quer fazer agora você está querendo armazenar uma linha do banco para cada grupo e comentário, contudo isso não é sustentável, por exemplo, qual o tamanho do campo que você irá usar para acomodar estes dados, o que você irá fazer quando houverem mais comentários do que você espera?

O ideal é armazenar de forma que cada comentário tenha seu próprio registro, com todas as informações pertinentes a eles.

Se o problema for performance ai é o caso de ajustar em outros pontos (indices, cache, etc).

Caso ainda deseje armazenar a array dentro do banco você ainda tem opções:

- Armazenar de forma plena (passar a array para string e armazena-la)

  - Neste caso você ainda tem os benefícios de poder buscar e alterar podendo ser direto no SQL como em outras linguagens (para APIs por exemplo).
- Armazenar seriada (passar pela serialização)

  - Você perde um pouco da capacidade de edição e leitura, visto que qualquer erro pode invalidar a informação.
- Encodar com Base64 ou outros algoritmos reversíveis.

---

### Solução 2

Uma outra opção caso deseje armazenar uma estrutura de dados que não seja rígida (como um banco relacional) é usar bancos NoSQL como Redis e MongoDB, onde você pode passar suas arrays inteiras para persistência.

Neste segundo caso você pode armazenar elas e recupera-las praticamente que pronto para uso.

Comment: **1.** Se você usar `implode` vai manter o valor mas vai perder as chaves. Serialize ou json são os indicados. **2.**  `base64_encode( string $data )`, logo não "criptografa" um array.

Comment: Vou tentar a solução do banco de dados NoSQL. Obrigado.